# listview with white-space for jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

**My Code:**

```html
<div data-role="content" id="merlin">
  <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" data-inset="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h2>That is a serious problem and I don't know how to solve it</h2>
       <ul data-role="listview">
         <li>some content</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**
http://s14.directupload.net/images/140117/6foqxhjr.png

**What I want:**
White-Space (or say word wrap?) to read the whole heading

**What I've tried:**

```css
#merlin {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

or

```css
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li-desc {
   white-space: normal;
}​
```

Comment: You should inspect the html and find the element with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` set to it and apply the `white-space: normal;` to it. Not to the parent div. As far as your `.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li-desc` is concerned - I don't see any classes in the html you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the class `ui-btn-text` and try this selector:

```css
#merlin .ui-btn-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBwU3/)**